# PostgreSQL: Conditionally combine values from two rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have inherited a table structure that I have queried to result in the following table:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| purchase  |  item       |  price  |  category  |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1         |   widget A  |  20.00  |  product   |
| 1         |   widget B  |  50.00  |  product   |
| 2         |   widget A  |  20.00  |  product   |
| 3         |   widget A  |  20.00  |  product   |
| 3         |   promo     |  30.00  |  product   | 
| 3         |   widget B  |   0.00  |  bundle    |
---------------------------------------------------
```

And I am trying to extract a specific report that combines the bundled product into the result of the promo item (as they are related), such that it looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| purchase  |  item               |  price  |  category  |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 1         |   widget A          |  20.00  |  product   |
| 1         |   widget B          |  50.00  |  product   |
| 2         |   widget A          |  20.00  |  product   |
| 3         |   widget A          |  20.00  |  product   |
| 3         |   promo - widget B  |  30.00  |  product   | 
----------------------------------------------------------
```

For any item that has a category of 'bundle', the price will be 0.00 and there will be a corresponding promo item as part of that same purchase. For now, I can assume that there is only one bundle product per purchase, but a solution that can concat multiple bundle items to one promo (eg. 'promo - widget B, widget C) would be even better.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: can you have two promo in same purchase?

Comment: No, only one promo would ever be present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assume only one bundle for purchase. Otherwise you need something to make the pairing.

- First you create a field category_type so can group the bundle together.
- Then use array_agg to put them together
- Finally join the bundles with the normal products.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/IUYK82204)**

```
WITH cte as ( 
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN "item" = 'promo' OR "category" = 'bundle' 
                   THEN 'bundle'
                   ELSE 'product'
              END as category_type
    FROM purchases
), bundle as (
    SELECT purchase, 
           array_to_string(array_agg(item ), ' - ') as "item", 
           MAX(price) as price, 
           MAX(category) as category
    FROM cte
    WHERE category_type = 'bundle'
    GROUP BY purchase
)    
SELECT * FROM bundle
UNION ALL
SELECT "purchase", "item", "price", "category"
FROM cte
WHERE category_type <> 'bundle'
ORDER BY "purchase"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the union of two selects is where I couldn't get myself to go :)

Comment: I just realize in the `bundle ` query you may add a `ORDER BY`  depending if you want the promo or the bundle name first.